# Monitor VM network with Little Snitch

Tags: vmware, firewall

I've upgraded to Big Sur (yep, late to the party), VM Ware Fusion 12 and Little Snitch 5.
I get that kernel extension are no longer valid and VM Ware now uses the Apple network API.

Previously I could block VM client network activity via little snitch for the `vmnet-natd` process. Useful for just general content blocking, but also used so I could isolate the VM without having to change the VM network to host only.

It looks like I'm no longer able to block or even capture any network traffic from VM with Little Snitch any more.

Any suggestions on alternative methods for doing this?

Ideally I'd like to block individual domains and hosts the VM client connects to. I'd also like to completely block the VM, i.e. have a host only connection.

For the 2nd option I realise I can set the VM to be host only. However this seems to completely reload `bootpd` config to a different IP address range. I want to avoid this as I need to keep services running on the same network in the VM.